# Alphanumeric sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want a sequence to start with AP0000001 and get incremented by 1 so the next value will be AP0000002 and so on

So following are the queries I tried for

1. Creating sequence
   Create sequence patient_no_seq
   Start with 0000001
   Increment by 1;
2. Creating a table
   Create table patient(
   id serial not null primary key,
   patient_no text not null default('AP' || nextval('patient_no_seq'));

When I try inserting the patient_no is incrementing in AP1, AP2... in this manner but I want it to get incremented as AP0000001, AP0000002... and so on

Comment: Try to_char(nextval(...), '0000000')

Comment: Instead of a sequence separate from the `id serial`, consider using a generated column. Having `id` and `patient_no` diverge is probably not what you want.

Comment: Do you even *need* this sequence in the database? Generating the formatted patient number from the `id`, and conversely, parsing formatted numbers into integers, could (should?) be done in the application.

Comment: Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of replacing your post with completely different content